# Influential papers in bioinformatics

Tags: literature-search

As a newcomer, what are some influential research papers published in the past few years that I should read to catch up in the field?

Edit: @Devon Ryan answered it perfectly. I tried a google search but it turned up a bunch of opinionated articles that varied. The biostar discussions are perfect and was the link I was searching for. I hope someone else new to the field finds this useful!

Comment: I think this is far too broad and opinion based for this site

Comment: I was pretty sure someone would point that out. It depends on how broad of a range we want to cover. Are we just here to answer specific technical questions? Or is this going to be more of a community? I personally agree and think this question might be better for the bioinformatics subreddit or Biostar.  I was just testing the waters while looking for an answer.

Comment: EMiller, The concern with this question is there's no problem statement... so the question is to generate an unbounded list of whatever folks care to post. An occastional, well-regarded "big list" question isn't generally a problem unless it becomes excessive, but please be careful of the inference that, if folks don't agree, this "isn't a community." I don't believe that was your intention here, but folks sometimes throw that out there as a backhanded way to discourage further discussion.

Comment: @EMiller there are some rules that apply to all Stack Exchange sites. The SE model is strictly Q&A so broad, discussion-based questions or requests whose answer will perforce be a long list (such as this one) will always be too broad.

Comment: @terdon "there are some rules that apply to all Stack Exchange sites. The SE model is strictly Q&A". I thought it was up to the moderators to decide when a question is unfit. That's a pity because on biostars I find questions like this often very interesting and still the volume of "bad" questions isn't too annoying, IMHO. Personally I don't see much point in having a site strictly for Q&A and another for general discussion. As I said, biostars is both and works well for me. Just my 2p...

Comment: @Robert I meant that a new commer with a specific question could just pop in and ask a question, without watching the community first like you might have to somewhere like biostar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over on biostars there's a thread like this every year or so. I'll link to [the 2016 edition](https://www.biostars.org/p/229807/) and the (much shorter) [2015 edition](https://www.biostars.org/p/171860/).

My personal picks from those would be:

- [ExAC](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v536/n7616/full/nature19057.html)
- [salmon](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2015/06/27/021592), which is now published
- [kallisto](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02710), which is also now published